# losing floating point when making a product between float and integer in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a new column containing a product between two numeric columns.
One is integers, other is double.
The result is losing any floating point positions.

Same operation in console with worked ok. The issue only appears executing this inside a script.

Option digits is not set. So this is not that kind of issue.

```
R>   df <- data.frame("first"= c(2,45,56), "second"= c(0.3425,1.4567,0.9234))
R> df %>% dplyr::mutate(new=first*second)
  first second     new
1     2 0.3425      0
2    45 1.4567     65
3    56 0.9234     51
```

Opening console pane and coding a product this way worked flawlessly as expected:

```
R> 2*0.3425
[1] 0.685
```

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this. It shows decimal for me. Run `options(digits = 10)` in the console and try to run again.

Comment: same issue. Not solved

Comment: I can't reproduce either, but try: `as.double(first)*second` this should convert to a floating point before the multiplication